# Вывод SUM для UNION запроса

Tags: sql

Добрый день. Есть запрос следующего вида:

```
SELECT COUNT(id) FROM A 
WHERE id_C = 2

UNION

SELECT COUNT(id) A FROM A
WHERE id_C = 3
```

Запрос урезал максимально, чтобы была ясна суть.

Есть результаты в таком виде:

```
4
7
```

Требуется к этому же результату добавить третьей строкой сумму предыдущих двух строк:

```
4
7
11
```

Такое возможно не запиливая дополнительного запроса вида:

```
SELECT COUNT(id) FROM A 
WHERE id_C IN(2, 3)
```

?

Comment: Без дополнительного запроса возможно, но решается всякими продвинутыми возможностями типа rollup или СTE. Поэтому сильно зависит от конкретной СУБД. rollup есть например в oracle. А подходящее CTE в MS SQL и postrges. Для произвольного SQL - только третий запрос в union c запросом что вы в конце написали

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Классически задача решается при помощи `WITH ROLLUP`. Однако, в MySQL он работает только в рамках одного запроса, в случае же `UNION` у вас два отдельных запроса. Можно поступить следующим образом

```
SELECT COUNT(id)
FROM A
WHERE id_C IN (2,3)
GROUP BY id_C
WITH ROLLUP
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ. Да, таким образом работает. Пытался разными способами решить задачу, но как оказалось не все так просто при работе с UNION.

Answer (score 4):

Без UNION и ROLLUP:

```
select count(coalesce(a,b)) from 
(SELECT id_C a FROM A 
where id_C in(2,3)
) X
full join 
(SELECT 4 b FROM A 
where id_C in(2,3)
) Y on 1=2
group by coalesce(a,b)
```

Comment: Да, такой вариант решает задачу, но было интересна именно связка с ключевым словом UNION.

Comment: Мне показалось, что с UNION вы знаете, как решить задачу. :-)

Comment: Без 3-го запроса не получается :)

Comment: Тогда в моих подзапросах можно использовать UNION вместо IN, если вас это устроит.